# How do you put changed data from frontend to backend without having to save unchanged values?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, vuejs2

So I importing a list from a database using axios and store it in a variable.
Let's call it tasks.
Each object could look something like this:

```
tasks: [
    { title: 'some text here' },
    { completed: false },
  ]
```

Imagine I have 2000 or 3000 of these.
On the frontend I make a checkbox for each task that sets the boolean value in completed to `true` or `false`

```
<li v-for="task in tasks">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="task.completed">
      <label :for="task.title">{{task.title}}</label>
</li>`
```

Great, now I need to save the changes so my database can be updated.

```
submit(){
    return axiosComponent.updateTask(this.tasks)

  }
```

Here's where my problem is. Upon clicking on submit, I'm going through the entire list of tasks and basically saving everything. This can lead to timeouts and other performance issues as it has to go through thousands and thousands of objects.
So what I would like to do is to somehow change the submit method so that it ONLY saves the data that has actually been changed.
So if two tasks have been set to false or true in "completed" then only save those two tasks to the database. Do not save the entire list.

I don't know if it's something I can do purely on the frotend or if I need to do something on the backend. For those interested, here is my backend code for the process:

**The axios component:**

```
updateTask(tasks){
    return axios.put('task/updateStatus', tasks)
  }
```

**The controller getting the axios data:**

```
@PutMapping("/updateStatus")
    public void updateStatusOnTask(@RequestBody List<TaskEntity> taskEntities){
        taskManager.updateTaskStatus(taskEntities);
    }
```

**The manager**

```
public void updateTaskStatus(List<TaskEntity> taskEntities) {
        taskRepository.saveAll(taskEntities);
    }
```

So what did I try? Well, one idea was to create computed properties that saved the checked and unchecked tasks in their own objects and then put these in my submit method instead of "tasks.

```
completedTasks(){
    if(this.tasks){
      return this.tasks.filter(task => task.completed)
    }
  },
  unresolvedTasks(){
    if(this.tasks){
      return this.errors.filter(task => !task.completed)
    }
  },

  submit(){
    return axiosComponent.updateTask(this.completedTasks)

  }
```

The problem of course is that I am not actually saving anything to the database when I save these. I do not change the values in the "tasks" object. I am just putting the changed values into a new one. So when I save and reload the page, they will get overwritten once the tasks object is loaded.
Also, if I have 1000 unresolved tasks, then we will have the same issue with timeouts if I need to save any changes to these.

Comment: The page on your frontend likely has the original dataset that came in through loading (e.g. API request). Can you use this and compare it to the form state when you press the submit button, and make an `object diff`, and send that to your backend instead?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the tasks from the api, you could map the tasks to something like this.

```
const tasks = [{ title: "some text here", completed: false }];
const internalTasks = tasks.map((task) => ({ ...task, touched: false }));
```

And the touched attribute gets set to `true` on the change event of the checkbox.

```
<li v-for="task in internalTasks">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    v-model="task.completed"
    @change="task.touched = true"
  />
  <label :for="task.title">{{ task.title }}</label>
</li>
```

Then you can filter the `internalTasks` and only send the changed tasks to the api.

```
submit() {
  return axiosComponent.updateTask(internalTasks.filter((task) => task.touched))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this requirement by making a copy of the original array and then on submit, You can compare the stringified version of the changed object with the cloned one.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tasks: [
      { title: 'Title 1', completed: false },
      { title: 'Title 2', completed: false },
      { title: 'Title 3', completed: true },
      { title: 'Title 4', completed: false },
      { title: 'Title 5', completed: true }
    ],
    clonedTasks: []
  },
  mounted() {
    this.clonedTasks = structuredClone(this.tasks);
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      const updatedTasks = this.tasks.filter(obj => {
        return !JSON.stringify(this.clonedTasks).includes(JSON.stringify(obj))
      });
      console.log(updatedTasks);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <li v-for="task in tasks">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="task.completed">
    <label :for="task.title">{{task.title}}</label>
  </li>
  <button @click="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```